# PHPExcel HTML writer with chart

Tags: php, html

I can see a chart in excel generated by PHPExcel, but when i save it to HTML (using HTML Writer) I can't see the chart. how to make the chart work in HTML Version?

here is my code when saving to HTML.

```
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xls, 'HTML');
$writer->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$tmpfile = TEMPFILE;
$writer->save($tmpfile);

echo file_get_contents($tmpfile);
```

Comment: What version of PHPExcel are you using? Some fixes have been made in the HTML Writer to the way charts are handled when they fall outside of the data range on the sheet since the 1.8.1 release

Comment: from what can i get in the filename, it is 1.8 (PHPExcel-1.8.zip). so, i have to update the version to 1.8.1?

Comment: No, those fixes are later than 1.8.1, done on 3rd August. You need the 1.8 branch from github